# Force php to use tcp instead of socket without changing mysql host from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, mysql

is there any way to force php to use a TCP connection instead of the socket file for local mysql connections without changing the host parameter from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"?

Scenario:

Up to now Apache/php and MySQL are on the same server. But for performance and high availability reasons I'm planing to relocate MySQL to another server. The new server will be replicated to a failover server. On the Apache/php server I want to use haProxy (tcp) for the connection handling. 
For data protection reasons I can't change the host parameter from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1".

Workaround:

The only solution I found is a workaround with socat:

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/path/to/mysql.sock,fork,user=mysql,group=mysql,mode=777 TCP:127.0.0.1:3306 2> /dev/null &"
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Why not use the hostname of the new server?

Comment: Why is data protection at risk if you use the IP address?

Comment: Probably used it for salting hashes.

Comment: I can't change the host parameter because this involves customers data. For the same reason I can't use the hostname of the new server. Furthermore I want to use haProxy for ha failover.

Comment: You are being very elusive but I guess @EJTH is right and you are using the MySQL host name to compose an encryption key, possibly in some third-party CMS were it isn't easy to change the algorithm. If `socat` works for you I'd say it's okay, yet the question is quite off-topic here since you are not interested in a code solution—it's possible that you'd get better solutions at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).